# How to prevent sorting of data grid view

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I am using a DataGridView on windows form. It displays just two columns. By default when the application is run, if I click on the column headers, the datagridview gets sorted based on that column. However, I want to disable sorting on the grid view completely. I was not able to find a property where I could set sorting = false, or something like that.

Can anyone please tell me how to disable grid view sorting?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Just figured I could set individual columns as NotSortable (posted answer below). Can it be done at the grid view level, rather than individual columns?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, found the answer. For each column I need to explicitly specify

```
this.dgv.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

So I wrote my own function in a Helper class

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the sort mode for the data grid view by setting the sort mode of individual columns
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dgv">Data Grid View</param>
/// <param name="sortMode">Sort node of type DataGridViewColumnSortMode</param>
public static void SetGridViewSortState(DataGridView dgv, DataGridViewColumnSortMode sortMode)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        col.SortMode = sortMode;
}
```

and wherever, I need to make grid views unsortable, I call it like this:

```
Helper.SetGridViewSortState(this.dgv, DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
```

Comment: This works nicely. I made this into an extension method and now can call it this way: `dgv.SetGridViewSortState(DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);`

Comment: Cool! I am glad the solution helped you :)

Comment: Is there no way to do this without looping through columns? I have a bound DataGridView with a large backing DataTable, and plenty of things like setting Cell background, setting AutoSizeColumnsMode, etc cause extreme performance bottlenecks. I just optimized my code by removing all those (we are always forced to compromise for performance with MS apps). Now I wonder if looping through 25 columns is a good idea at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
Next i
```

web gridview has a property AllowSorting which is much easier!

Comment: Yes, eventually thats what I am doing. However, it still is at column level and not grid level.

Comment: Cool! Works in VB.NET, I wonder why there's no upvote on this.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is, in part, a feature of the data-source. What is the data source in this case? `DataTable`, perhaps? One option is simply to use a data-source that doesn't support sorting, which is almost all of them. `List<T>`, `BindingList<T>` etc - don't provide sorting.

If you must use `DataView`, you could (I guess) wrap the view with a custom view that re-implements `IBindingList` (returning `false` for `SupportsSorting`), but simply changing the values per column is a **lot** easier (to the point where it would be *crazy* to do anything else...)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create your own function

```
Private Sub NotSortGrid()
        For i = 0 To dgvUtil.Columns.Count - 1
            dgvUtil.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When you add a code block to your post, you must include at least four spaces before each line for it to be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I use a binding source and a datatable for my datagridview. In order to bypass all the underlying autosorting done by the dataview I have a database id number for each row so I can use the datagridview to make a list of my id numbers (FROM THE SELECTED ROWS) then i can search my datatable for each record and make the change there. I could probably just do the same thing straight to the datagridview itself. to be clear im not actually sure if im bypassing the auto sorting but the method here does not miss any rows due to them moving in an auto sort. This may not be good if your database is very large as it involves searching the entire database for each record.

I have a database of employees and i can select multiple rows and then select a job code from a combobox and click the button to set the jobcode for each row. I might not be needing to suspend the binding source but anyways...

heres my code.

```
Private Sub SetCodeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetCodeBtn.Click
    If current_db_name = "employees" Then
        Dim db_id_col As Integer = FindDataGridColumn("DB_ID", DataGridView1.Columns)
        Dim job_code_col As Integer = FindDataGridColumn("JOBCODE", DataGridView1.Columns)
        Dim new_job_code As String = JobCodesCBX.Text
        Dim db_id_list As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            db_id_list.Add(row.Cells.Item(db_id_col).Value)
        Next
        For Each id As String In db_id_list
            For Each table_row As DataRow In tables_data("employees").Rows
                If table_row(tables_data("employees").Columns.IndexOf("DB_ID")) = id Then
                    table_row(tables_data("employees").Columns.IndexOf("JOBCODE")) = new_job_code
                End If
            Next
        Next
        table_changes_made = True
        RefreshDataGridView(DataGridView1)
        BindingSource1.ResumeBinding()
    Else
        MsgBox("You Must Select Rows In The Employees Database To Set A Job Code.")
    End If
End Sub
```

[Screenshot of my Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJy4l.png)

Answer (score -1):

You could always handle the column header click and double click events yourself, and do nothing in them.

Answer (score -1):

Staring with .NET 3.0, the GridView has a property called AllowSorting